# MyBatis @insert value type string to value type text

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I'm new in MyBatis and MySql

I'm trying to insert value with annotation to MySql DB

In the Entity class I have:

```
private String name;
private String description;

    ... getters and setters
```

In MySql table I have:

```
name VARCHAR(20);
description TEXT;
```

1 - Do I have to convert the type from String to TEXT ?
2 - If yes, how do I do it ?(With annotation and **not** XML file), I tried to do it like this but it doesn't work.

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO table1 SET  name = #{name}, description = #{description, jdbcType=TEXT }")
public int save(Entity entity);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: i don't know mybatsi but  ... TEXT is a string ..  just long up to 64k

Comment: @JBD mybatis doesnt provide a jdbcType `TEXT`. the [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) says: "In most respects, you can regard a BLOB column as a VARBINARY column that can be as large as you like. Similarly, you can regard a TEXT column as a VARCHAR column" so changing `jdbcType=TEXT`to `jdbcType=VARCHAR` or `jdbcType=LONGVARCHAR` should work

Comment: Well I found out I don't need to map a String to a VARCHAR or a TEXT, it's automatic.